# Visual Studio Team Services - How to Setup a NativeScript Build?

Tags: azure-devops, angular2-nativescript

I'm just starting a new project using NativeScript + Angular and have hosted the code in Visual Studio Team Services.  I'm brand new to NativeScript however I want to have a Build Definition setup to build the iOS and Android artifacts for Continuous Integration.

When I build locally, I do the following command: `tns build` however I'm unclear how I would be able to use this in a Team Services Build Definition.  Right now my build definition only consists of

1. Get Sources
2. npm install
3. ??? (where I'd like to do `tns build` here)

It currently fails because it doesn't know what the `tns` command is and as far as I'm aware, I cannot install these tools on an agent since its a hosted instance. 
 Appreciate any thoughts or alternative ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer, you need to set your global directory and add it to the path.
Feel free to remove the debugging comments.

```
echo 'This is the current path.'
echo $PWD
echo 'This is the global path.'
npm prefix -g 
echo 'Setting the npm prefix path'
npm config set prefix "$PWD/NPM"
echo 'Setting path'
PATH=$PATH:"$PWD/NPM/bin"
npm install nativescript -g

echo "PATH: $PATH"
tns doctor
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working. I did this yaml pipeline in Azure Devops.

### For ios

```
- task: UseNode@1
      displayName: "Use Node ${{ parameters.nodeVersion }}"
      inputs:
        version: XX.XX
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'npm clean'
      inputs:
        command: custom
        verbose: false
        customCommand: 'run clean'
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: 'npm install nativescript'
      inputs:
        command: custom
        verbose: false
        customCommand: 'install nativescript@6 -g'
    - task: PythonScript@0
      displayName: "Install python package six"
      inputs:
        scriptSource: 'inline'
        script: |
          import os
          os.system("pip install six")
    - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
      displayName: "Install an Apple provisioning profile"
      inputs:
        provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
        provProfileSecureFile: ${{ parameters.iosProvisionProfile }}
    - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
      displayName: "Install an Apple certificate"
      inputs:
        certSecureFile: 'devops-cn.p12'
        certPwd: ${{ parameters.certificatePassword }}
        keychain: 'temp'
        signingIdentity: 'iPhone Distribution: Whatever Company'
    - task: PythonScript@0
      displayName: "Build"
      env:
        IOS_PROVISION_PROFILE_NAME: ${{ parameters.iosProvisionProfileName }}
        IOS_IPA_FILE_NAME: ${{ parameters.iosIpaFileName }}
      inputs:
        scriptSource: 'inline'
        script: |
          import os, shutil
          os.system("tns build ios --bundle --provision \"{}\" --for-device --release".format(os.environ.get('IOS_PROVISION_PROFILE_NAME')))
```

### For Android

```
- task: UseNode@1
  displayName: "Use Node XX.XX"
  inputs:
    version: XX.XX
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: "npm install"
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'run clean'
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: "npm install nativescript"
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'install nativescript@6 -g'
- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: "Build"
  env:
    AND_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD: ${{ parameters.androidKeyStorePassword }}
    AND_KEY_STORE_ALIAS: ${{ parameters.androidKeyStoreAlias }}
    AND_KEY_STORE_ALIAS_PASSWORD: ${{ parameters.androidKeyStoreAliasPassword }}
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      import os
      
      os.system("tns build android --bundle --release --key-store-path \"$(secureFile.secureFilePath)\" --key-store-password \"{}\" --key-store-alias \"{}\" --key-store-alias-password \"{}\"".format(os.environ.get('AND_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD'), os.environ.get('AND_KEY_STORE_ALIAS'),  os.environ.get('AND_KEY_STORE_ALIAS_PASSWORD')))
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add install NativeScript Command-Line interface by using NPM task, for example:

1. NPM task 1.* (Command: custom; Command and arguments: install nativescript –g)
2. Command Line (call tns command) (Tool: tns; Arguments: --help)

On the other hand, you can [setup a private build agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows), then running it as your account (change service account)

Note: Based on my test, it works fine with Hosted Linux Preview agent; it throws error with Hosted agent (not supported platform)