# How to create a Azure Pipeline for a NativeScript Angular app?

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nativescript

I am developing a NativeScript Angular app. and I want to automate the process of build for iOS and Android devices whenever any `commit` OR `merge` is made to the `main` branch. Preferably using the Azure Pipelines.

So, more like whenever the `main` branch is updated, the build for iOS (.ipa) and Android (.apk) files should kick-in and the output should be the .ipa and. apk files.

Is there any documentation or possible ways I could implement this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a Azure Pipeline for a NativeScript Angular app?

You can create an Azure repository to store your NativeScript Angular source code.

Then create a azure pipeline to build the source code for the `main` branch with **Enable continuous integration**:

[image]

[image]

You could check the document [NativeScript Testing with Azure Pipelines](https://nativescripting.com/posts/azure-pipelines-testing) and [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667131/visual-studio-team-services-how-to-setup-a-nativescript-build) for some more details.